# I don't know how to stop the recursion in my code

Tags: recursion

```
def histogram(items):
for n in items:
    output = ''
    times = n
    while (times > 0):
        output += '*'
        times = times - 1
    print(output)
histogram(items)
```

own_num = int(input("   Enter your number: "))
res = [int(x) for x in str(own_num)]
histogram(res)

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop any recursive function in any programming language, you need to create the **command-branching**, which will play a role the command **"base case"**. In the solution of your problem, shown below, command **"base case"**:

```
if(start>stop)
{
    return;
}
```

This command allows to cut the **"recursive tree"**, which will created during an execution of the command-function **"recursiveFunction"**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void showContentString(string& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<input[i];
    }
    return;
}
void recursiveFunction(int start, int stop, string& inputString)
{
    if(start>stop)
    {
        return;
    }
    inputString.append("*");
    recursiveFunction(start+1, stop, inputString);
    if(start==0)
    {
        cout<<"inputString <- ";
        showContentString(inputString);
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    string symbols;
    recursiveFunction(0, 11, symbols);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
inputString <- ************
```